# Swing Jar to exe conversion

Tags: java, swing, deployment, executable

I have a quick question. I am trying to convert Jar to Exe using Launch4j.
JRE version I use is jre1.8.0_91.

So, on launch4j on "JRE" tab I specify Bundled JRE Path as `\bin\jre1.8.0_91`.

1. Does the exe file works on other machines which have lower JRE Versions?
2. Is it mandatory to use JRE Path on Launch4j or can I just use Min JRE Version and specify 1.0.0.0 ? so that it can work on higher versions.

Comment: *"I have a quick question."* I have a quick question as well - what is the meaning of life? Just because your question is 'quick', does not mean the answer is! And BTW - *"Qestion1: .. Question 2: .."* that's *two* questions. General notes: The best way to deploy a Java desktop application is using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info). The best way to create  a Windows Exe is using a Windows language (like ..VB or something).

Answer (score 1):

> Does the exe file works on other machines which have lower JRE Versions?

It will work if the bundled jre is executable on the target machine (32-bit, 64-bit).

But a bundled JRE does not mean that it is included in the exe file. It just means that the exe will look up the jre in the specified path. Usually you want to specify a relative path.

Furthermore the path must be a **path to the jre executable** and not the jre home.

E.g. if you specify the jre path as `jre/bin/java.exe` your folder structure should look like this:

```
- Your.exe
  +- jre
     +- bin
        - java.exe
```

Now you can e.g. zip the whole directory and deploy the zip file.

> Is it mandatory to use JRE Path on Launch4j or can I just use Min JRE Version and specify 1.0.0.0 ? so that it can work on higher versions.

It's not mandatory but the exe might not be able to locate a suitable jre on the target machine. I would use the bundled way to ensure that the application works well.

But if you can you should consider to use [Java Web Start](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/) instead.